# Failed to insert into postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

I am using this to create table:

```
dbconn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='123456'")
cur=dbconn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE Person
(
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
""")
```

But when I try to insert into the database with this:

```
>>> cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Persons (LastName,FirstName,Address,City) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s');""",("aa","bb","cc","dd"))
```

This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Persons (LastName,FirstName,Address,City) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s');""",("aa","bb","cc","dd"))
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "aa"
LINE 1: ...rsons (LastName,FirstName,Address,City) VALUES (''aa'',''bb'...
```

Comment: You need to commit your transaction with `dbconn.commit()` otherwise your table won't get created.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid tried! but it does not work!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Persons (LastName,FirstName,Address,City) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", ("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"))
```

example from [psycopg documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html):

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",
...      (100, "abc'def"))
```

Comment: Still it does not work! :(

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Person (LastName,FirstName,Address,City) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", ("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"))
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`